# Run HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute without HttpContext.Current

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to execute an aspx page on the server in a background process, render that as a PDF and send it via email.

While I can get the string representation of the page easily using `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute`, I cannot do this on a background process because `HttpContext.Current` is null.

Here is my function:

```
Public Function GetHTML(ByVal as_Page As String) As String
    Dim ls_HTML As String
    Try
        Dim lsw_Html As New StringWriter
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(as_Page, lsw_Html, False)
        ls_HTML = lsw_Html.GetStringBuilder().ToString()            
    Catch ex As Exception
        ls_HTML = String.Empty
    End Try
    Return ls_HTML
End Function
```

How can I execute a page on a background process?

Comment: Couldn't you add another parameter your function: `Public Function GetHTML(ByVal as_Page As String, ByVal context As HttpContext) As String` then call it like: `GetHTML("something", HttpContext.Current)`? (or replace the `HttpContext.Current` parameter with yet another variable)

Comment: @VisualVincent: No. In a background process, there is no HttpContext, hence I cannot pass in anything.

Comment: Is the context needed, or could you just download the page using a WebClient?

Comment: What I meant was can't you store the current context in a variable from a non-background process, then pass that to your method? (I'm not much into ASP.NET so I don't know if this is possible at all, just suggesting)

Comment: @VisualVincent: No, the HttpContext cannot be stored out of context of a page request.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: No, the context is not needed. The page is a local page on the same site - hence I didn't want to use a WebClient for performance reasons.

Comment: @navigator You might as well give it a go - at least then if it is too slow then you have data showing that more effort needs to be put into sending the page as a PDF. And if it's fast enough, then the task is done :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible either you are "inside" and have HttpContext or you are "outside" and only way is http protocol (WebClient).